# Web Scraping News Headlines and Time

Tags: r, web-scraping

my goal is it to webscrap news headlines with time from the following site:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(polite)

col_link = "https://www.finanznachrichten.de/nachrichten/nachrichten-alle.htm"
bow(col_link)
col_page = read_html(col_link)

scraped_tables <- col_page %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)

scraped_tables[[2]]
```

The result is only the first page.
What it does not catch are the next 4 pages and the hours. I uploaded a image with circles. The url is not interactive, so I can not just use a loop to catch all patches.

Can somebody give me any advice? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the webpage itself, it has a selection of links under the table that suggest pages (you already know this):

[image]

For me, mouse-over does not reveal the target URL, but if you open the browser devtools (not R's `devtools` package), often with `F12` or such, go to the "Network" tab and then click on one of the pages, you'll see the fetched URL:

[image]

You can use that template to iterate over tables until you get no more data.

```r
read_html("https://www.finanznachrichten.de/w/289/1?tab=0&page=26") |>
  html_table()
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 20 × 5
#    Zeit  `Aktuelle NachrichtenSprache:             \nAlle DE EN`                                                   Medien               ``    ``              
#    <chr> <chr>                                                                                                     <chr>                <lgl> <chr>           
#  1 14:15 "Danish non-alc producer ISH talks up \"tremendous\" potential in off-premise"                            Just Drinks          NA    ""              
#  2 14:15 "Nicht erschrecken, wenn diese Google-Seite plötzlich einen neuen Look hat"                               SmartDroid           NA    ""              
#  3 14:15 "Neue Gemini-App für Android startet, aber nicht in Deutschland"                                          SmartDroid           NA    ""              
#  4 14:15 "Small launch companies seek niches to compete with SpaceX rideshare"                                     SpaceNews            NA    ""              
#  5 14:15 "Netflix enthüllt alle Highlights für 2024"                                                               TECHBOOK             NA    ""              
#  6 14:15 "Höhere Prämien treiben Hannover Rück an"                                                                 Versicherungsmagazin NA    ""              
#  7 14:15 "China's NEV exports up 27.1 pct in January 2024: association"                                            Xinhuanet            NA    ""              
#  8 14:15 "Bayer: Neue Probleme am Horizont"                                                                        4investors           NA    "In den USA bek…
#  9 14:15 "Gratis war gestern: Nur noch 4 Prozent der Onlinehändler bieten kostenlosen Versand"                     t3n                  NA    "Immer weniger …
# 10 14:15 "Tata Communications arbeitet mit Microsoft zusammen, um Sprachanrufe über Microsoft Teams zu verbessern" news aktuell         NA    "Mumbai, Indien…
# 11 14:15 "IAA Transportation 2024 mit Bus-Themenpark"                                                              Automobil Industrie  NA    ""              
# 12 14:15 "Mofas, Mopeds, E-Scooter: Schilderwechsel steht bevor"                                                   cash-online.de       NA    ""              
# 13 14:15 "Wachtendorf-Kolumne: Zertifikate-Schwemme: Tatort Sparkasse"                                             DAS INVESTMENT       NA    ""              
# 14 14:15 "Volvo Global All-Electric Car Sales Improved In January Thanks To EX30"                                  InsideEVs            NA    ""              
# 15 14:15 "Playtech nets 2028 extension to Boylesports partnership"                                                 SBC News             NA    ""              
# 16 14:15 "Mysteries of the Orient: Unveil the Secrets with Endorphina's Oriental Dragon"                           European Gaming      NA    ""              
# 17 14:15 "Politiker gehen viral: Wieso kann wirklich jeder ein TikTok-Star werden?"                                futurezone           NA    ""              
# 18 14:15 "Aufgewärmter Reis ist \"tödlich\": Das steckt hinter der TikTok-Panik"                                   futurezone           NA    ""              
# 19 14:15 "Spritzer inks JV agreement to develop housing project in Perak"                                          The Edge Markets     NA    ""              
# 20 14:15 "Court strikes out LCS subcontractors' lawsuit against BHIC, directors"                                   The Edge Markets     NA    ""
```

Unfortunately ... `page=27` returns the same table, so it took me some time to know that `page=26` was the last page ... and I have no confidence that it will always be `=26`. Especially since you are trying to be `polite`, while I cannot find a way to know how many pages exist ahead of time, you will want to be very careful to look for *any rows* that have already been return. Here's a somewhat-okay process to get them all:

```r
tables <- list()
page <- 1
while (TRUE) {
  this <- read_html(paste0("https://www.finanznachrichten.de/w/289/1?tab=0&page=", page)) |>
    html_table()
  if (any(sapply(tables, function(tb) anyDuplicated(rbind(tb, this[[1]])) > 0))) break
  tables <- c(tables, this)
  page <- page + 10 # use +1 in reality, I'm just being `polite` :-)
}
page
tables <- do.call(rbind, tables)
tables
# # A tibble: 80 × 5
#    Zeit  `Aktuelle NachrichtenSprache:             \nAlle DE EN`                                                                       Medien      ``    ``   
#    <chr> <chr>                                                                                                                         <chr>       <lgl> <chr>
#  1 14:51 "Opening Bell: PayPal, Adyen, Roblox, PepsiCo, GoPro, Mattel"                                                                 Der Aktion… NA    "Wie…
#  2 14:51 "PayPal: Die Kursziele purzeln"                                                                                               finanztref… NA    "Pay…
#  3 14:51 "Siemens: Allzeithoch!"                                                                                                       finanztref… NA    "Die…
#  4 14:51 "Von Studis bis zu Beauty & Health: APG mit 18 neuen Zielgruppen im Digitalen"                                                Klein Repo… NA    ""   
#  5 14:51 "Krebsforschung: Deutschland kann beim Forschungsboom nicht mithalten"                                                        RND.de      NA    ""   
#  6 14:51 "Betreiber zuversichtlich: Gasspeicher erneut zu 100 Prozent befüllbar"                                                       RND.de      NA    ""   
#  7 14:50 "ERSTE AG: Suspension of trading in and the removal of EBBMWTS14 turbo warrant and the possibility of Residual Value Trading" Budapest S… NA    ""   
#  8 14:50 "Universal Investment: \"Stehen nicht im Wettbewerb mit Kunden\""                                                             fondscheck… NA    "Wie…
#  9 14:50 "Rosenberger, Langer & Cie. ernennt Andreas Langer zum Geschäftsführer"                                                       fondscheck… NA    "Bad…
# 10 14:50 "Stabilitas Gold+Resourcen Special Situations-Fonds: 01/2024-Bericht, Wertrückgang von 11,3%"                                 fondscheck… NA    "Bad…
# # ℹ 70 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Notes:

1. I increment by `page + 10` here for demonstration, you probably want `page + 1`.
2. I'm choosing to not `tables <- rbind(tables, this[[1]])` every pass in the `while` loop for many reasons (notably, see [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), *"Growing Objects"*); in this case it might be "just fine", but it can get out-of-hand quickly, so this method of `rbind`ing each of the tables within `tables` with `this[[1]]` puts a bound on the memory growth.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with F12. I see now how I can get that urls. That solves for a long time problem. This was so annoying me.